# Where can I find the theorem regarding the weight distribution of a $[2^m-1, m+1, 2^{m-1}-1]_2$-BCH codes?

Tags: coding-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}:=[n, k, d]_2$ denotes a binary linear code of block length $n$, dimension $k$, and minimum distance $d$. Now, for a positive integer $m$, a  $[2^m-1, m+1, 2^{m-1}-1]_2$-BCH code has the following weight distribution:

$$
a_0 = 1 ,\\
a_{2^m - 1} = 1,\\
a_{2^{m-1}-1} = 2^{m}-1 ,\\
a_{2^{m-1}} = 2^m - 1,\\
a_{j} = 0,\ \mbox{for other j's},
$$
where $a_i$ denotes the number of codewords of weight $i$.

Now, I know that the above weight distribution is true, but I don't know the proof of it. Even if I knew the proof of this weight distribution, it would not help me because I am writing a research paper where I need to mention this weight distribution but giving the proof of it would go beyond the scope of my paper. Therefore I am searching for a published research paper or a book where I can find a theorem regarding the proof of weight distribution of the $[2^m-1, m+1, 2^{m-1}-1]_2$-BCH codes. If I find such a theorem, I would cite it straight away in my paper. Can somebody give the direction on where I might find the weight distribution of such BCH codes?

Comment: This code is the _dual_ of the _expurgated_ $[2^m-1,m,4]_2$ binary Hamming code of length $2^m-1$.It might be easier to look for the weight distribution of the $[2^m-1,m,2^{m-1}]_2$ maximal-length linear feedback shift register code whose weight distribution can be found in Golomb's _Shift-Regioster Sequences_ or Berlekamp's _Algebraic Coding Theory_ or MacWilliams and Sloane's _Theory of Error-correcting Codes.Part II_, to name just a few references.

Comment: This is the (punctured) first order Reed-Muller code. I'm sure that most textbooks have the weight distribution. Normally I would start with MacWilliams & Sloane, but my copy is in my office, and I plan to work remotely today.

Comment: If you are writing a term paper for school, then you may need to dig up a reference. For a journal I would not bother. This is the one family of codes every coding theorist knows the weight distribution of anyway. I would not bother with a reference, but that may be due to my math upbringing, where only necessary references are included.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify, the m-sequence code Dilip Sarwate mentioned in the comment has
weight distribution:

$$
a_0 = 1 ,\\
a_{2^{m-1}} = 2^m - 1,\\
a_{j} = 0,\ \mbox{for other j's},
$$
since its nonzero codewords are precisely the cyclic shifts of the m-sequence.

Your code is this code, plus this code translated by adding the all 1 vector.

This gives you a full weight codeword as well as the complements of the m-sequence shifts, each of weight $2^{m-1}-1.$

Comment: +1 for providing the details of the weight enumerator of the $m$-sequence code, but note that what the OP wants is _references_ to books or papers wherein the exact weight distribution of that specific code is given as a Theorem or an entry in a table etc., and I don't know of any specific reference for that. All the books I know state the weight distribution of the _extended_ code which has nice symmetries and only even-weight codewords or the expurgated $m$-sequence code whose codewords have only one nonzero weight.

Comment: @kodlu ; I don't understand. Are you saying a $[2^m-1, m, 2^{m-1}]_2$ $m$-sequence code and its complements constitute the kind of BCH codes I am looking for?

Comment: yes, I don't have much time now, but as @DilipSarwate pointed out finding the full weight distribution won't be easy [I had a quick look last night].

Comment: @kodlu ; Ok, but where can I find the weight distribution of $[2^m -1,\ m,\ 2^{m-1}]_2$ $m$-sequence code? I had a quick look into the references given by Dilip Sarwate, but I couldn't find the weight distribution $m-$sequence code.

Comment: The m-sequence has all the cyclic shifts of the sequence as its nonzero codewords, so it has $2^m-1$ codewords of weight $2^{m-1}$. Add to those the all zero codeword to make it a linear code. Another name used for this code is the "simplex code" (it must be over binary alphabet though): https://www.encyclopedia.com/computing/dictionaries-thesauruses-pictures-and-press-releases/simplex-codes

Comment: @kodlu ; Ok, according to your answers, a $[2^m-1,\ m,\ 2^{m-1}]_2$ $m-$sequence code and its complements constitutes a $[2^{m}-1,\ m+1,\ 2^{m-1}-1]_2$-BCH code. Which would imply that $[2^m-1,\ m,\ 2^{m-1}]_2$ $m-$sequence code is indeed a $[2^m-1,\ m,\ 2^{m-1}]_2$-BCH code. But where can I find that the proof that a $[2^m-1,\ m,\ 2^{m-1}]_2$ $m-$sequence code is actually a $[2^m-1,\ m,\ 2^{m-1}]_2$-BCH code?

Comment: "Where can I find the proof..." I don't have an explicit answer but note that the $m$-sequence code is a cyclic code with parity-check polynomial a primitive binary polynomial whose roots are $\alpha, \alpha^2, \alpha^4,\cdots, \alpha^{2^{m-1}}$. So, $\alpha^{2^{m-1}+1}, \alpha^{2^{m-1}+2}, \alpha^{2^{m-1}+3}, \cdots, \alpha^{2^{m-1}+2^{m-1}-1}$ all are roots of the generator polynomial, making the BCH lower bound on the minimum distance to be $2^{m-1}$.